# How can I dynamically add items to an onsen-list without angular?

Tags: onsen-ui

```
<ons-list id="myList"></ons-list>
```

Then a statement in a loop that does

```
$('#myList').append("<ons-list-item>" + variableItem + "</ons-list-item>");
```

And probably some sort of a refresh like so

```
$('#myList').listview('refresh');
```

after exiting from the loop.

Can this be done without angular?

Answer (score 5):

Add item via javascript, like:

```js
var listElement = document.getElementById('myListElement'); //My ons-list element
var newItemElement = document.createElement('ons-list-item'); //My new item
newItemElement.innerText = 'Lorem ipusm dolor'; //Text or HTML inside

//Update ons render
ons.compile(listElement);
```

Answer (score 3):

@Rafa's answer is correct, but you seemed to use jQuery instead of plain JS.
@Ataru's answer utilizes jQuery, but lack ons.Compile();
ons.compile() is required to generate regular HTML from onsen directives (custom [Web Components](http://onsen.io/blog/tutorial-favorite-star-button-javascript-web-components-api/)) since not all browser support them (yet).

Here's sum up:

`$('#myList').append("<ons-list-item>" + variableItem + "</ons-list-item>");`
`ons.compile($('#myList')[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="yourApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- If you don't use Monaca, please comment out here and load Onsen UI directly.  -->
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>

        var yourApp = angular.module('yourApp', ['onsen']);
        yourApp.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
        
        // Add new list ith jQuery.
        var onsList = $("#ons-list-test");
        onsList.append('<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">Item 1</ons-list-item>');
        onsList.append('<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">Item 2</ons-list-item>');
        onsList.append('<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">Item 3</ons-list-item>');
        onsList.append('<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">Item 4</ons-list-item>');            
        onsList.append('<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner" style="background:#999999;">Item 5</ons-list-item>');
                            
    });
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="page1.html">
  </ons-navigator> 
</body>
</html>
```

page1.html

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Navigator</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <div style="text-align: center" ng-controller="listCtrl">
    <ons-list id="ons-list-test">
        
    </ons-list>
  </div>

</ons-page>
```

Thank you.

[image]You can add your new list by using jQuery as following:

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
<ons-list id="list4" >
  <ons-list-header>Grocery list</ons-list-header>
  <ons-list-item >Broccoli</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item>Oranges</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>

 <script>
var m = "Apples & Pears"
var item = ons._util.createElement("<ons-list-item> </ons-list-item>");
item.innerHTML = m;
document.getElementById("list4").appendChild(item);
  </script>
```

Maybe you have to add compile to it, the internet is not sure about it (-;